# How can I regain access to my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

I attempted to log into my Facebook account from my cell phone. I didn't know that my cell phone wasn't connected to my Facebook account. I am now blocked from my account because of this. I'm being asked for my old password and I don't remember it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Login and password frequently asked questions: [Login Basics](http://www.facebook.com/help/login)

[Resetting password](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144?helpref=topq):

You can use the **Forgot your password?** link located near the **Login** button on the Facebook home page.

Or [Find Your Account](https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate) to request a new password.

If you request a new password, you will be asked to identify your account. These tips may help with the process:

[I can't find my account from the "Find Your Account" page.](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19511)

Facebook doesn't offer personalized email support for login issues, but you can find more information through these resources:

- [Security questions](https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844?helpref=related)
- [Recovering your account through friends](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1153)
- [Troubleshooting](https://www.facebook.com/help/374104332645037?helpref=faq_content)
- [Report Hacked Account](https://www.facebook.com/hacked)